# Build Docker image using GitHub Actions: No such file or directory

Tags: docker, github-actions

We intend to use Git Actions to build our Docker on every commit.

This is our current Git Actions yml:

```
# This is a basic workflow to help you get started with Actions

name: CI

# Controls when the workflow will run
on:
  push:
    branches: 
      - '**'
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - '**'

  # Allows you to run this workflow manually from the Actions tab
  workflow_dispatch:

# A workflow run is made up of one or more jobs that can run sequentially or in parallel
jobs:

  docker-build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      
      - name: Navigate to app folder
        run: cd app
      - name: Open Directory
        working-directory: app
        run: |
          ls -la
      - name: Build docker image
        run: docker build . -t app_name -f Dockerfile
```

The error I get is:

```
unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile path: lstat /home/runner/work/git-root/app/Dockerfile: no such file or directory
```

But in my `ls -la` i see the Dockerfile is present:

```
total 48
drwxr-xr-x 4 runner docker 4096 Sep 15 13:03 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 runner docker 4096 Sep 15 13:03 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 runner docker   93 Sep 15 13:03 .env-template
-rw-r--r-- 1 runner docker  655 Sep 15 13:03 Dockerfile
```

I have tried:

- Using both `actions/checkout@v1` and `actions/checkout@v2`
- cd into the directory with the Dockerfile
- setting Dockerfile directory to working-directory

Why does not the docker build find my Dockerfile?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the docs [here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsrun):

> Each `run` keyword represents a new process and shell in the runner environment. When you provide multi-line commands, each line runs in the same shell.

This means that the working directory isn't persisted after the `cd` step. Your `ls` step works because you explicitly set the working directory for it.

You have to `cd` in the same run step as the build command:

```yaml
      - name: Build docker image
        run: |
          cd app
          docker build . -t app_name -f Dockerfile
```

Or you could set a working directory:

```yaml
      - name: Build docker image
        working-directory: ./app
        run: docker build . -t app_name -f Dockerfile
```

Or you can give docker the path to your dockerfile:

```yaml
      - name: Build docker image
        run: docker build app -t app_name
```

The default for `-f` is `PATH/Dockerfile`, where `PATH` is `app` above.