# Github action Error: Dockerfile does not exist in location Dockerfile

Tags: github-actions

i need to build and push my docker image on dockerHub but i'm getting error on path Dockerfile.

i had learn other ([Build Docker image using GitHub Actions: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69204872/build-docker-image-using-github-actions-no-such-file-or-directory))
but i don't understand how can resolve this error.

```
service:
      runs-on: ubuntu-latest
      defaults:
        run:
          working-directory: ./microservices/service

      strategy:
        matrix:
          node-version: [16.x]

      steps:
      - name: CHECK-OUT GIT REPOSITORY
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
          cache: 'npm'
          cache-dependency-path: '**/package-lock.json'
      - name: INSTALL DEPENDENCIES
        run: npm ci
      - name: BUILDING APP
        run: npm run build --if-present
      #- name: TESTINT APP
      #- run: npm test
      - name: Build & push Docker image
        uses: mr-smithers-excellent/docker-build-push@v5
        with:
          image: dockercountname/aos_movie_service
          tags: latest
          registry: docker.io
          dockerfile: Dockerfile
          username: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_PASSWORD }}
```

My Local directory:
i have many subForlder for each service and each service contains his Dockerfile.

```
microservice_cicd(forlder)
   microservices(forlder)
     service1(forlder)
       package.json
       Dockerfile
       ...
     service2(forlder)
       package.json
       Dockerfile
       ...
```

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:latest
RUN mkdir -p /src/app
WORKDIR /src/app
COPY package.json /src/app/package.json
RUN npm install
COPY . /src/app
EXPOSE 3003
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

Comment: Well where is your DockerFile

Comment: Thank you for you answer. My Dockerfile is in microservice_cicd>microservices>service>Dockerfile.

Comment: Hello, i have get other error actually, ```Step 4/7 : COPY ./package.json ./
COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat package.json: file does not exist```

I seaching solution. Don't hesitate someone can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally i had find a solution.

Workflow

```
  AuthService:
      runs-on: ubuntu-latest
      defaults:
        run:
          working-directory: ./microservices/AuthService

      strategy:
        matrix:
          node-version: [16.x]

      steps:
      - name: CHECK-OUT GIT REPOSITORY
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
          cache: 'npm'
          cache-dependency-path: '**/package-lock.json'
      - name: INSTALL DEPENDENCIES
        run: npm ci
      - name: BUILDING APP
        run: npm run build --if-present
      #- name: TESTINT APP
      #- run: npm test
      - name: Build & push Docker image
        uses: mr-smithers-excellent/docker-build-push@v5
        with:
          # directory: /microservices/AuthService
          image: dockerHubCountName/aos_movie_auth_service      
          tags: latest
          registry: docker.io
          dockerfile: microservices/AuthService/Dockerfile
          username: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_PASSWORD }}
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:latest
RUN mkdir -p /src/app
WORKDIR /src/app
COPY microservices/SearchService .
RUN npm install
EXPOSE 3003
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

Thank you.

Comment: But locally if need to build your image don't forget replace ```COPY microservices/SearchService .  by COPY .  .```